# A tiny problem with the teensy board

Tags: microcontroller, teensy

I am trying to follow an instructable to use a teensy micro-controller board. At step 6 it tells me to select tweensy(USBKeyboard/Mouse) from the board menu. However, my board menu does not have this option, even though I have patched the Ardunio environment per the previous steps and I do see a lot of other teensy board options. Has anyone else seen this and found a fix.

The instructions do call for the Arduino 18 environment. I am usingArduino22, could this be the problem? I don't want to install two environments unless I have to.  Thanks for any help that you may offer.

James.

Comment: I've used the teensy with the arduino22 environment so I doubt that's the problem. Could you link to the instructable so we know what steps you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions at http://pjrc.com/teensy/teensyduino.html? You have to install some stuff to use the Arduino environment for Teensy - this combination is affectionately known as Teensyduino...